Understanding the Statement "Yesterday is Sunday, Tomorrow is Monday" at 00:00 Midnight Boundary
I encountered a statement that says, "yesterday is Sunday, tomorrow is Monday," and I'm trying to understand it in terms of day conventions around midnight (00:00).
Here's my reasoning so far:
At exactly 00:00, we are at the boundary between Sunday and Monday.
If we consider 00:00 as an undefined or "neutral" point (neither fully Sunday nor fully Monday), then:
Yesterday is still Sunday (the last completed day).
Tomorrow is Monday (the upcoming full day).
By standard convention, 00:00 is assigned to Monday, so we would conclude that today is Monday.
This interpretation seems to satisfy both parts of the statement while assigning "today" as Monday based on convention.
Questions:

Is my interpretation correct in viewing 00:00 as an undefined boundary point that can logically satisfy the statement before assigning it to Monday?

Are there any mathematical or philosophical considerations in treating 00:00 this way, or is there a standard approach to understanding such boundary cases?


I'd appreciate any insights or alternative viewpoints on handling this type of boundary condition. Thank you!

"At exactly 00:00, we are at the boundary between Sunday and Monday." : This is wrong.  At exactly 00:00, it is Monday, rather than the boundary between Sunday and Monday.

Apparently rather ambiguous. See especially the section "Start and end of day".
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight#:~:text=As%20the%20dividing%20point%20between,with%20the%20hour%2000%3A00.

I don't think that this is a question for mathematics. I guess that you are thinking of $0$ being neither positive nor negative (1) and trying to extrapolate from that.  However, real life usage of the terms won't necessarily be based on that.  In any computer system that I have seen, 00:00 is part of the new day but caution is still worthwhile.  Airlines avoid scheduling flights at exactly 00:00 to reduce danger of confusion.
(1) Most of the time but the Bourbaki school proposed that $0$ was both positive and negative.
